# Why my view isn't rendered inside _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am learning ASP.NET from book **Pro ASP.NET 4.0** but I have stucked on adding CartController and Views/Cart/Index.cshtml

I have added something like this:

```
public class CartController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

        public CartController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml", new CartIndexViewModel
            {
                Cart = GetCart(),
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            });
        }

        public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

            if (product != null)
            {
                GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }
        private Cart GetCart()
        {
            Cart cart = (Cart)Session["Cart"];
            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                Session["Cart"] = cart;
            }
            return cart;
        }
       }
     }
```

Then I have added to my Cart->Index action view (right click->Add View), like this:

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.CartIndexViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Sklep sportowy: Twój koszyk";
}

<h2>Twój koszyk</h2>
<table width="90%" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center">Ilość</th>
            <th align="left">Produkt</th>
            <th align="right">Cena</th>
            <th align="right">Wartość</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var line in Model.Cart.Lines) {
        <tr>
            <td align="center">@line.Quantity</td>
            <td align="left">@line.Product.Name</td>
            <td align="right">@line.Product.Price.ToString("c")</td>
            <td align="right">@((line.Quantity * line.Product.Price).ToString("c"))</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="right">Razem:</td>
            <td align="right">
                @Model.Cart.ComputeTotalValue().ToString("c")
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<p align="center" class="actionButtons">
    <a href="@Model.ReturnUrl">Kontynuuj zakupy</a>
</p>
```

In my Product Summary on the page I have a button that adds Product to Cart and then redirects to this `localhost:port/Cart/Index` page. Here is this navigation button:

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product

    <div class="item">
         <h3>@Model.Name</h3>
         @Model.Description

         @using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" value="+ Dodaj do koszyka" />
         }
         <h4>@Model.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
    </div>
```

The problem is that the Cart works perfectly well but it's view isn't embedded in main layout `/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. It just appear as separate page that doeasn't include any html headers or body stuff, just content section of the website.

The github project of the same example I have found is done exactly the same way as the main Visual Studio project. https://github.com/akatakritos/SportsStore

I have checked the book code listings and I cannot find any errors. Why it doesn't appear correctly as the part of the main layout? But is in separate view!

Thx for any help.

EDIT:

I have Views/Shared/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to set Layout in _ViewStart.cshtml? Something like this @{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your _ViewStart.cshtml to `Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` (instead of Views/Shared/). MVC is not looking for it in the Shared folder.